# How to pass in event data for jQuery datepicker events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to pass event data to a jQuery datepicker event handler, for 'dataID':

```
        input.datepicker({
            onClose: function() {
                var datePicker = jQuery(this);
                customFunction(datePicker, dataID);
            }
        });
```

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Pass the current object as:-

```
input.datepicker({
            onClose: function(txt, obj) {
                var datePicker = obj;
                customFunction(datePicker, datagridId);
            }
        });
```

onClose method gives two arguments. The text entered and the this instance where the event occurs.

Check the reference here

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onClose

Comment: I mean to pass 'dataID' as an argument into the function.  'dataID' is declared outside the event handler. If I directly use 'dataID' I encounter a problem with javascript closure